# Dump DDL and Data of DB2 with DataGrip Ultimate

Tags: db2, datagrip

I'm just recently starting to use Datagrip and DB2 engine. Is there a way to export both DDL and Data into 1 SQL file and then later run the file to create a new schema.
[image]

[image]

I only see there a option to export ONLY DDL or ONLY Data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This forum is about programming for Db2.  Your question is about how to use a proprietary tool (jetbrains datagrip).  Better to ask your question on jetbrains discussion group for datagrip  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200381555-DataGrip

Comment: I am Max from DataGrip and we follow SO questions as well :) So it's a valid platform to ask and get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is currently impossible, please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10677

Comment: Okay, thanks for your confirmation. That's help :)